# Simultaneous User Testing

Tags: automation

My requirement is to test when four to six different users accessing the web application from different locations and doing the same functionality at the same time.In such scenario which testing tool i should use?To perform such testing can i use selenium webdriver using testNG(session handling)?For example if 6-10 users are creating gmail account from different locations at the same time(complete the functionality of account creation),then i want to see the performance of the web application wheather it has been performed smoothly without any delay or hiccups .

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) with [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/), you can write automated tests to simulate your scenario

[JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) or LoadRunner can provide metrics such as response times and resource utilization.